# Can Photoshop export directly to a website or external link?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, plugins

How extendable can Photoshop functionality be made? Can one create a plugin/extension/script that can give you 1-click or 2-click ability to save or export and publish directly to a website?

Answer (score 2):

There is alternatives to implementing a FTP / SFTP / Webdav client directly in Photoshop.

For example, [win-sshfs](http://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/) allow you to mount a remote SFTP server as a disk.

See also the answers to [How can I mount an FTP to a drive letter in windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/6079/how-can-i-mount-an-ftp-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows).

An other possibility is using WebDAV, or a Sync client.

[Pydio](http://pyd.io/) has both possibilities. Setup Pydio on your server and configure it to allow users to edit your web site images folder contents.
Enable webdav access in Pydio.

On your OS, setup a WebDav client (integrated in most OS), and use Photoshop to save to this client.

Alternatively, you can use the [Pydio sync client](http://pyd.io/apps/desktop-sync-client/) for your OS.

I've written a [Pydio installation guide](http://howto.biapy.com/en/debian-gnu-linux/web-applications/files-management/install-ajaxplorer-web-file-manager-on-debian). It may help you.